# Create Dynamic Drawer Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a three category.This category define in state variable.Now i want this category will be display inside React Drawer Navigator.

**Here is my code**

```
constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        myCategory: [
          {
            category: 'Category1'
          },
          {
            category: 'Category2'
          },
          {
            category: 'Category3'
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
     // display category

    });
const MainStack = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Current version of React Navigation has a static configuration API, which means all configuration must be done outside render. This makes use cases such as dynamic navigators impossible until React Navigation 4.

React Navigation 5 has a new component-based API to configure navigators, which makes dynamic navigators possible:

```js
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function DrawerScreen() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([
    'Category1',
    'Category2',
    'Category3',
  ]);

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      {categories.map(category => (
        <Drawer.Screen name={category} component={MyComponent} />
      ))}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/next

Keep in mind that React Navigation 5 is still in alpha.